# Directive not updated after factory call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive that has a single attribute called content. I'm trying to pass data to this directive's attribute via an outer's controller scope variable called x. This seems to work fine by setting x equal to 'xyz' at the start of the controller, but when I make a call to a factory to pull a value to update the x variable the data isn't being reflected in the directive. I can see that $scope.x is being set to the return value from the factory within the controller, but it's not then updating the directive.

I seem to missing something somewhere. I'm guessing it's a scope problem but I'm just not seeing it. I've tried to simplify my issue into a Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/wsWzSTJ9VDprfTaToeHv).

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: will it work for your use case simply to add a $watch to the directive's controller? [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b49kJXnxvLxoTWigPD2T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem as noted in the comments is a missing $watch in the directive controller.. the controller doesn't "know" that `content` variable has changed..

so adding a $watch in the controller (the directive controller!) would solve this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.content}, function(){
  $scope.text = $scope.content
})
```

A working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bchWDGMmmc4LHfbLhtm4?p=preview)

Good luck!